Is there evidence for Egypt's potential motive in sabotaging a Hamas-Israel ceasefire deal?
Earlier today, CNN reported that an Egyptian intelligence official quietly made changes to a document and thereby scuttled a ceasefire deal between Israel and Hamas.
An Israeli official stated that this was done to make Israel look bad, but the report presents no further evidence for this.
Egypt's general policy towards Hamas is apparently complicated. According to a 2021 commentary Egypt has generally been hostile towards Hamas but sought common ground with them against the IS insurgency in Sinai. That insurgency seems dormant if not dead.
All parties involved in the negotiations were apparently shocked by Egypt's actions. Is there any analysis that might help explain what Egypt hoped to achieve by undermining the ceasefire deal? Is there reason to support the Israeli view? Is it possible that this was done by a rogue official acting on his own motivations? Does Egypt benefit from the war? Is making Israel look bad important enough to explain why Egypt would risk its reputation as a negotiating partner?

If true their motive wasn't necessarily sabotage. It could be they realized that there are no terms agreeable to both Israel and Hamas  so they figured they would change some on the hope that once Hamas announced that it agreed to a ceasefire plan accepted by Israel somehow that would hold even though it wasn't what Israel signed on

My understanding is that the ceasefire proposal that Hamas "accepted" was their own document, which differed from the document presented to them by Egyptians. So now they simply engage in a blame-game. Note that even the original Egyptian document was not quite accepted by Israel - there is some bickering about the meaning of terms like "ceasefire", "cessation of hostilities", etc., as Israel wants to continue eventually the war against Hamas, while Hamas seeks the end of the conflict and remaining in power - consistent with their earlier positions.

FWTW, Egyptian intel officials have now said the whole CNN story was a fabrication https://english.ahram.org.eg/News/524092.aspx
